# on two decompositions of a finite group $G$

Tags: group-theory

Let $G=A\times B\cong A\times C$. Then prove that there exists an isomorphisms $\gamma$ of $B$ to $C$ such that $Ab=Ab^\gamma$ for any $b\in B$.

we use $b^\gamma$ instead $(b)\gamma$.

Comment: Automorphism $\gamma\colon B\rightarrow C$ means $B=C$, otherwise it is an isomorphisms.

Comment: Ok. thank you. I correct it.

Comment: Do I miss something? People really use $b^\gamma$ instead of $\gamma(b)$, $\gamma b$ or $(b\gamma)$?

Comment: @tohecz I believe it is a common notation in the finite group theory (though that notation may reserved for conjugation).

Comment: Strictly speaking, $A \times B = A \times C$ implies $B=C$. So presumably the equality signs should be replaced by isomorphism signs.

Comment: @tohecz, the exponential notation for homomorphisms is particularly handy when you want to consider their *pointwise sum*, as it reads $g^{\alpha + \beta} = g^{\alpha} g^{\beta}$. Of course in general $\alpha + \beta$ will not be a homomorphism.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For every $b \in B$, from the hypothesis,
$$ b = 1b \in A \times B = A \times C. $$
Hence, there exists unique $a_b \in A$ and $c_b \in C$ such that $b = a_b c_b$. Then define a map $\gamma \colon B \to C$ by $b^\gamma = c_b$.

The map $\gamma$ is a homomorphism:
For every $x, y \in B$,
$$\begin{align*}
(xy)^\gamma &= (a_x c_x a_y c_y)^\gamma \\
&= (a_x a_y c_x c_y)^\gamma & \text{($A$ and $C$ commute)} \\
&= c_x c_y = (a_x c_x)^\gamma (a_y c_y)^\gamma \\
&= x^\gamma y^\gamma.
\end{align*}$$

The homomorphism $\gamma$ is injection:
If $b^\gamma = 1$ then $b = a_b c_b = a_b b^\gamma = a_b$. Since $A$ and $B$ has trivial intersection, $b = 1$.

The homomorphism $\gamma$ is surjection:
For every $c \in C$, there exists $a \in A$ and $b \in B$ such that $c = ab$ since $c = 1c \in A\times C = A \times B$. Therefore $b^\gamma = (a^{-1}c)^\gamma = c$ as desired.

$Ab \subseteq Ab^\gamma$: For every $ab \in Ab$, 
$$ ab = a a_b c_b = a a_b b^\gamma \in Ab^\gamma. $$

$Ab^\gamma \subseteq Ab$: For every $ab^\gamma \in Ab^\gamma$,
$$ ab^\gamma = a c_b = a {a_b}^{-1} a_b c_b = a {a_b}^{-1} b \in Ab. $$

The proof completes.

Comment: As noted by @DerekHolt in a comment to OP, if you are assuming $A \times B = A \times C$, then by the very definition of the Cartesian product you have $B = C$, so you might well take $\gamma$ to be the identity.

Answer (score 3):

As stated at the moment I am writing, the claim

> Let $G=A\times B\cong A\times C$. Then prove that there exists an isomorphisms $\gamma$ of $B$ to $C$ such that $Ab=Ab^\gamma$ for any $b\in B$.

is generally untrue.

Let $B_{i}$ be copies of a cyclic group $B$ of order $4$, and $C_{i}$ copies of a cyclic group $C$ of order $2$. Consider
\begin{equation*}
A = \prod_{i=1}^{\infty} B_{i} \times \prod_{i=1}^{\infty} C_{i}.
\end{equation*}
Then clearly
\begin{equation*}
A \times B \cong A \cong A \times C
\end{equation*}
while of course $B \not\cong C$.

Comment: +1 very nice, it just shows that people should be carefull about what they claim! However, it IMHO means that the OP likely wanted $AB=AC$ instead of $A\times B\cong A\times C$, which is what the other answer proves, and where your counterexample fails.